# Delete a collection from TFS

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I want to use a free tfs account for a sample project. So i created a free account on visualstudio.com and created 2 collections. And i want delete one them but i cannot delete it.

There is no any members in the collection. It doesn't allow me to delete. As you see on the screenshot, delete button is disabled. Also Is there any way that if i've an admin account, is possible to change or delete collections from visual studio?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure how/if it applies to free TFS versions, but the following link shows how to delete Team Project *Collections* in general. Looks like doing it via command line tool is the way to go.
https://rules.ssw.com.au/do-you-know-how-to-delete-a-team-project-collection

Here is the main part:

1. On TFS server, open Administrative Command Prompt and change to TFS Tools Directory.

   ```
   %programfiles%\microsoft team foundation server[versionnumber]\tools
   ```
2. Type the command:

   ```
   TFSConfig Collection /delete /collectionName:[COLLECTION NAME]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing [collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd236915.aspx) and team projects. You cannot create a collection in Team Foundation Service as of now. That may or may not change in the future. When you sign up, there is one collection created for you and that one will contain your team projects and you will need to live with that one. If you have a need to have another collection then you can sign up under another account. You can however delete team projects but not from the web UI. You will need to use the command line tool DaveShaw gave a link for. You can also check out the blog post below:

[How to delete a team project from Team Foundation Service (tfs.visualstudio.com)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2011/09/19/how-to-delete-a-team-project-from-tfs-on-azure.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You look like you are trying to deleted a "Team" from a "Team Project"? You have to have at least one "Team" in a "Team Project", and that will have the same name as the "Team Project".

If you are wanting to delete the entire "Team Project" (containing all the Work Items, Source, Builds, etc), you can do it using the [`tfsdeleteproject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181482.aspx) command line tool.

Comment: I think he tries to delete the entire collection which has to be done using the Administration Console. Is there something like that on Team Foundation Service?

Comment: @PVitt Not that I know of, but the screen shot is of deleting a team.

Answer (score 0):

Even we had similar issue. Unfortunately we had deleted a Collection DB without Stopping and Detaching the collection from TFS admin console in TFS 2018. Later we tried to detach the collection, but no luck. Initially we had ignored this issue since it was  test TFS collection and that too in QA server. Later during up-gradation to Azure DevOps 2019 server we faced issue with Existing Deployment option. we couldn't complete the upgradation. we followed below steps to fix the issue:

**1. Restored the VM/QA TFS server with VM snapshot backup created before upgradation.

2. Run below command to remove the deleted collection from TFS Config DB.

   **"TFSConfig Collection /delete /collectionName:[COLLECTION NAME]"**
3. Stop TFS services and done upgradation to Azure DevOps Server 2019 successfully.**